# How to solve the exception Illegal character in path?

Tags: android

I am displaying images from an URL using XML parsing and some images are displaying very well, but sometimes I get exception like

> Illegal character in path at index 113: http://www.theblacksheeponline.com/party_img/thumbspps/12390867930_15951_186997180114_709920114_4296270_6115611_n[1].jpg

How to solve this problem, please provide some sample code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with the URISyntaxException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Special characters need escaping such as `%5B` for [ and `%5D` for ]

You can use the `java.net.URLEncoder` to encode the URL as in

```
java.net.URLEncoder
```

URLEncoder.encode(myurltoencode,"UTF-8");

This will not just fix the [ or ] but also other encoding issues

Answer (score 4):

use this escape code for [  `%5B` 
and for the closing ] use `%5D`

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.theblacksheeponline.com/party_img/thumbspps/12390867930_15951_186997180114_709920114_4296270_6115611_n[1].jpg");
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
```

URLEncoder is used for web forms `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mime-type - not http network addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to handle this problem in a Java program or servlet would be to use [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org).

For example, if using Maven to build your program, add the following to your pom.xml file

```
<properties>
    <owasp.version>1.2.1</owasp.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
        <artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
        <version>${owasp.version}</version>
    </dependency>     
 </dependencies>
```

And then call the [Encode.forHtml](https://owasp.github.io/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html) method:

```
String safeStr= Encode.forHtml(str);
```