# Illegal character in path at index 16

Tags: java

I am getting the following error in RAD:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/E:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base......
```

Could you please let me know what is the error and how to resolve it?

Comment: See [how to solve this exception Illegal character in path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753852/how-to-solve-this-exception-illegal-character-in-path)

Comment: try replacing the spaces with '%20'

Comment: See general solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception/15570670#15570670

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There's an illegal character at index 16.  I'd say it doesn't like the space in the path.  You can [percent encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) special characters like spaces.  Replace it with a %20 in this case.

The question I linked to above suggests using [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
String thePath = "file://E:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base";
thePath = URLEncoder.encode(thePath, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: file:/// is files. Note the three

Comment: Hm... it doesn't really work: space is replaced with plus sign, not with %20, and also all the slashes are destroyed too...
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737841/urlencoder-not-able-to-translate-space-character

Comment: Do not use URLEncoder as written below by John it only make things worse.

Comment: I encountered this error [ java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 14: file:/20160703 Tour de France 2016 - stages.csv ] when I was using "cycli" (a Neo4j command line utility) to import data from CSV files via a Cypher script.  My CSV file names contained spaces; I replaced those with underscores, and the error went away.

Answer (score 27):

I ran into the same thing with the Bing Map API. URLEncoder just made things worse, but a `replaceAll(" ","%20");` did the trick.

Comment: Perhaps there are other characters that need to be encoded? Like `[`?

Comment: I had an extra space at the end of the URL by accident. Removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: this worked for me..

Answer (score 14):

Did you try this?

```
new File("<PATH OF YOUR FILE>").toURI().toString();
```

Comment: When the 'correct' answer doesn't work. This one is simpler and works...and probably works on multiple platforms too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem with spaces. Combination of URL and URI solved it:

```
URL url = new URL("file:/E:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base");
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
```

* Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/749829/435605

Comment: My problem was that I was using `file://c:/..`, but as you posted here it is `file:/c:/...` (just one slash)

Answer (score 2):

I had a **similar problem for xml**. Just passing the error and solution (edited Jonathon version).

**Code:**

```
HttpGet xmlGet = new HttpGet( xmlContent );
```

**Xml format:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee>
    <code>CA</code>
    <name>Cath</name>
    <salary>300</salary>
</employee>
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 0: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<contents>
    <portalarea>CA</portalarea>
    <portalsubarea>Cath</portalsubarea>
    <direction>Navigator</direction>
</contents>
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:69)
    at de.vogella.jersey.first.Hello.validate(Hello.java:56)
```

**Not Exactly perfect Solution:** ( error vanished for that instance )

```
String theXml = URLEncoder.encode( xmlContent, "UTF-8" );
HttpGet xmlGet = new HttpGet( theXml );
```

**Any idea What i should be doing ?** It just cleared passed but had problem while doing this

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( xmlGet );
```

Answer (score 0):

the install directory can't have space.
reinstall the software will correct it

Comment: that's one way to solve it but I think you were being sarcastic, right?

Comment: This is the sort of backward thinking that let us drag cumbersome remainders of the 70s and 80s in current day software - and waste unnecessary amounts of time and money. Current day software must be capable to handle spaces in paths and non-latin characters, using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs with the jdk use this :

progra~1 instead of program files in the path example :

```
 c:/progra~1/java instead of c:/program files/java
```

It will be ok always avoid space in java code.....

it can be used for every thing in program files, otherwise put quotes at the beginning and the en of path

"c:/..../"