# java.net.URI.create exception

Tags: java, uri

```
java.net.URI.create("http://adserver.adtech.de/adlink|3.0")
```

throws

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: 
Illegal character in path at index 32: http://adserver.adtech.de/adlink|3.0
```

although

```
new java.net.URL("http://adserver.adtech.de/adlink|3.0")
```

works just fine.

**UPDATE 1**

although

```
new org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI("http://adserver.adtech.de/adlink|3.0")
```

also works perfectly.

What's the reason?

Comment: Use  URLEncoder.encode as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992317/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-16

Comment: yeah, but question is why it works for `java.net.URL` and does not for `java.net.URI`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Both `URI.create()` and `new URI()` throw that exception. In the case of `URI.create()` it is wrapped in an `IllegalArgumentException` as per the Javadoc. Java version 1.7.0_17.

Comment: you reproduced exactly what I have. I have the exception whith `URI.create` and don't have it with `new URL()`

Comment: *Do not* use URLEncoder for this.  URLEncoder is for form encoding, not for escaping characters in a URI.

Comment: Yeah, better to use `URIUtils#encodeUri` from Apache's commons-httpclient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor of URI that takes a single String argument requires that you follow the strict syntax rules that RFC 2396 defines for URIs. According to those rules `|` should be encoded as `%7C`. The other constructors can encode the URI components for you, so for example this won't throw an exception:

```
new java.net.URI("http", "//adserver.adtech.de/adlink|3.0", null);
```

The URL class on the other does not enforce the URI syntax rules. In fact, it is your responsibility to encode the components that should be encoded; the URL class won't help you. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html):

> It is the responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields, that are returned from URL.

Comment: The java.net.URI constructors in question have existed since java 1.4

Comment: iv missread it, i thought it is a 2 arg constructor.