# java.net.URISyntaxException:Invalid character at index 69 when deploying war in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

I am trying to deploy a war file in `weblogic`. I am getting the following `error message`:

```
 java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path [1] at index 69:
 https://xxxxxxxxxxx.test-secure-xxxxxxx-processing.com/xxxxxx/CNP_2_1
```

The character in the question is `_ (underscore)`. Is there any way to solve it?

The URL has been defined in the beans `xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

There's an illegal character at index 69.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992317/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-16)

Comment: There are no spaces in the path. We double-checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Please use encode utils in order to  get ridoff special symbols in URL

```
String url = URLEncoder.encode("your url here","UTF-8"));
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding) also.