# ballerina: error while loading built-in package 'ballerina/lang/errors/'

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I tried to run a sample .bal file in Ballerina Samples folder which I downloaded from www.ballerinalang.org and I got this error.

[image: [The error]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by a URI encoding issue owing to the space in the file path (`Program Files`). Can you try from a different location with no spaces in the file path? Refer [Illegal character in path at index 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992317/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-16) for more details on this error.

Comment: I moved the files from the above mentioned location to "C:\", then it worked. Thanks

Comment: Great.. please accept the answer if you found it helpful :)