# App engine standard java 8 on windows 10 gives http error 503

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, java-8

Hi I am getting the following error when I run app engine on my local

[image]

I am using IntelliJ IDE and I have configured Google App Engine as per the instructions on the java 8 quickstart for App Engine Standard - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart-java8

The output window shows the following

```
Starting the App Engine local development server...
2017-07-01 20:29:47.591:INFO::main: Logging initialized @561ms
Jul 01, 2017 10:29:47 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader checkWorkingDirectory
WARNING: Your working directory, (C:\windows\System32) is not equal to your 
web application root (C:\Code\Java\getting-started-java\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target\helloworld_java8_GAE_standard-1.0-SNAPSHOT)
You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.

2017-07-01 20:29:47.954:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
Connected to server
2017-07-01 20:29:48.089:WARN:oejur.Resource:main: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.18.v20170406-nolog.jar
2017-07-01 20:29:48.090:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@385c9627{/,file:///C:/Code/Java/getting-started-java/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld/target/helloworld_java8_GAE_standard-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Code\Java\getting-started-java\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target\helloworld_java8_GAE_standard-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.18.v20170406-nolog.jar
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.getURI(Resource.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.isFromExcludedJar(AnnotationConfiguration.java:784)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.getNonExcludedInitializers(AnnotationConfiguration.java:877)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.AppEngineAnnotationConfiguration.getNonExcludedInitializers(AppEngineAnnotationConfiguration.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1363)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:346)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:262)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:359)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
Caused by: 
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.18.v20170406-nolog.jar
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.getURI(Resource.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.isFromExcludedJar(AnnotationConfiguration.java:784)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.getNonExcludedInitializers(AnnotationConfiguration.java:877)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.AppEngineAnnotationConfiguration.getNonExcludedInitializers(AppEngineAnnotationConfiguration.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1363)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:346)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:262)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:359)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
2017-07-01 20:29:48.109:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@3857f613{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
2017-07-01 20:29:48.110:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1076ms
Jul 01, 2017 10:29:48 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Jul 01, 2017 10:29:48 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Jul 01, 2017 8:29:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992317/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-16 plz check this

Comment: @Vinjay, I have the same issue, this is definitely a bug with App Engine since we can't control escaping this path. Any solution? Do you know the right place to open a bug report?

Comment: No, I don't I am told that Google check's StackOverflow. I moved the Google  SDK to a folder without spaces. It's working now.

Comment: Just received this error after having to roll the Cloud SDK back to version 159.0.0 due to an App Engine Search API issue. Removing the space did the trick, thanks!