# Nimbus openid - can't parse Azure OIDC Metadata

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, nimbus

When calling

```
Issuer issuer = new Issuer("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
OIDCProviderConfigurationRequest oidcProviderConfigurationRequest = new OIDCProviderConfigurationRequest(issuer);

HTTPRequest httpRequest = oidcProviderConfigurationRequest.toHTTPRequest();
HTTPResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.send();

OIDCProviderMetadata.parse(httpResponse.getContentAsJSONObject());
```

I get the following

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 24: https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.util.JSONObjectUtils.getURI(JSONObjectUtils.java:527)
```

How can i overcome this ?

Comment: Have you tried to encode url?

Comment: Not sure i understand, but the decoding is done on nimbusds level.

Comment: Hmm, as the error shows, the URL has illegal characters. If the {tenantid} is null, it may also cause the error at `{}`.

Comment: I know - the Azure discovery return a illegal URL and nimbusds can't handle this. The question is there is a way to overcome this?

Comment: The error message is telling you where to look. Look at the 24th character of the path.

Comment: Will it make an error if you change `{tenantid}` to the real id `https://sts.windows.net/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a7xxxx/`? In addition, be careful not to include `spaces`, `_`, `{}` and other illegal characters in the URL.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but it seems that problem is more than just a URL decoding. I need to figure out also what is the meaning of the {tenantid} , there is a reason why Nimbus fails to parse the discovery content returned from Azure

Comment: It is your tenant id: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sqWa.png

Answer (score 0):

(Moving from Comments to Answer)

The error message is telling you where to look. Look at the 24th character of the path.You need to make sure that `spaces`, `_`, `{}` and other character cannot appear in the URL.

For how to solution the problem of common illegal characters in URL, there are general solutions, it is recommended to use [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Please see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992317/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-16).