# Passing an array as argument of a java program in bash

Tags: java, bash, shell, parameter-passing

I am running a Java program through a bash script.
My plan is to iterate over a for-loop to create the argument to pass:

```
lastLine=$(cat $info_file | wc -l)

countID=0

cat $info_file | while read fileID; do

initVar="${initVar} ${fileID}.txt"

countID=$(($countID + 1))

if [ "$countID" == "$lastLine" ]; then
echo $initVar > tmp_${SampleID}.txt
fi

done

InputListVar=$(cat tmp_${SampleID}.txt)

java ProgramX --input "${InputListVar[@]}" --output $output_file
```

However, when I run the script above I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 15
```

I suppose that this is due to the space in the list of files I provide within the `InputListVar` array (as suggested here [Illegal character in path at index 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992317/illegal-character-in-path-at-index-16)). How could I solve this issue?

Comment: If this were me I would rewrite the Java program to read in the file.

Comment: Ok, I am trying all of your suggesting. Coming back in a min.

Comment: This last suggestion worked pretty well! I would suggest to give a reply to my question for upvoting it. Also, I think that others may find it useful. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: You didn't specify what is stored on `InputListVar`, and what your Java program is actually doing with the argument to the `--input` option. I would read the documentation which (hopefully) comes with your Java program, and then ensure that the correct parameters are passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't work with `java` but I'm assuming `java` wants to see something like:

```
java --input file1 file2 file3 --output ...
```

OP's script should generate this format *IF* `InputListVar` is defined as an array, but it's not.  The following creates a scalar variable:

```
InputListVar=$(cat tmp_${SampleID}.txt)
```

If we assume the following contents of the input file:

```
$ cat tmp_${SampleID}.txt
file1
file2
file3
```

Then we get the following:

```
$ InputListVar=$(cat tmp_${SampleID}.txt)
$ typeset -p InputListVar
declare -- InputListVar=$'file1\nfile2\nfile3'
```

So when this is fed to `java` the following happens:

```
java --input "${InputListVar[@]}" --output ...

# becomes

java -- input file1
file2
file3 -- ouput ...

# hence an error
```

**NOTE:** `${InputListVar}` is technically the same as `${InputListVar[0]}` so OP's `${InputListVar[@]}` becomes `${InputListVar[0]}` which becomes `${InputList}`

We can 'fix' the issue by insuring we're working with an array:

```
InputListVar=( $(cat tmp_${SampleID}.txt) )           # note the additional pair of outer parens
```

Back to the `java` call:

```
java --input "${InputListVar[@]}" --output ...

# becomes

java -- input file1 file2 file3 -- ouput ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have got Bash 4.0 or later (for `readarray`) this code may do what you want:

```
readarray -t fileids <"$info_file"
java ProgramX --input "${fileids[@]/%/.txt}" --output "$output_file"
```

- `readarray -t fileids <"$info_file"` makes each line of "$info_file" an element of the `fileids` array.
- `"${fileids[@]/%/.txt}"` expands to the (quoted) elements of `fileids` with `.txt` appended to each of them.