# how to remove java.net.URI syntax exception

Tags: java

I am using the following code to show NSE indices in default browser.

```
String downloadURL = "http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=AkieA" +
   "_4_rXXRBh2SH7_U3kXyULlG;_ylu=X3oDMTE1Nmc5cjBnBHBvcwMyBHNlY" +
   "wNmb290ZXIteWZpbmFuY2UEc2xrA25pZnR5NTA-?s=^NSEI";
java.awt.Desktop myNewBrowserDesktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
java.net.URI myNewLocation = new java.net.URI(downloadURL);
myNewBrowserDesktop.browse(myNewLocation);
```

The URL in mention has been copied from yahoo site itself. However, when i run the code , i get error like:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal
>   character in query at index 140: 
>   http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=AkieA_4_rXXRBh2SH7_U3kXyULlG;_ylu=X3oDMTE1Nmc5cjBnBHBvcwMyBHNlYwNmb290ZXIteWZpbmFuY2UEc2xrA25pZnR5NTA-?s=^NSEI

I dont know what is wrong ; i have done the same with other URLs with success. Please help.

Comment: I changed my URL to http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^NSEI . Still, it shows Error. So , i removed ^ from the query. It works, but i dont get the page i want. isnt ^ allowed in URL in java

Comment: For general solution have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception/15570670#15570670

Comment: For a more general solution have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20874602/205607 ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per this link:

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm the Caret ("^") comes under unsafe category.

> "Unsafe characters" Why:  Some
>   characters present the possibility of
>   being misunderstood within URLs for
>   various reasons. These characters
>   should also always be encoded.

After changing the `^` to %5E it works.

Now if you copy the url from your browser and put it in another browser then it will work. I think the browser internally takes care of the `special` characters. But in java the `java.net.URL` is supposed to work with standalone and console applications and as well on different platforms, therefore, it is the responsibility of the developer to take care of encoding `special` characters.

Google for java based URL encoders.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should URL-encode your string:

```
URI myNewLocation = new URI(URLEncoder.encode(downloadURL, "UTF-8"));
```