# URL error, Exception:Illegal character in query at index 185

Tags: android, url

What's wrong with my URL :

http://emapzoom.com/gpslocation/upload_location?status=1&lat=0.422005&lng=-122.084095&alt=0&mph=0.0&dir=0.0&dis=1.359023E7&lm=GPS&sid=4500352380545078953&acc=0.0&tm=1311847202000&tm2=28 Jul 2011 10:00:02 GMT&did=10169

i got in my log cat

07-29 10:11:16.995: VERBOSE/Exception doing background(334): Exception:Illegal character in query at index 185: 
http://emapzoom.com/gpslocation/upload_location?status=1&lat=0.422005&lng=-122.084095&alt=0&mph=0.0&dir=0.0&dis=1.359023E7&lm=GPS&sid=4500352380545078953&acc=0.0&tm=1311847202000&tm2=28 Jul 2011 10:00:02 GMT&did=10169

Comment: so what's wrong i can get respond when i type it in browser but in android it got error

Answer (score 5):

How about changing the spaces to %20

Comment: Change every space in that url to %20
http://emapzoom.com/gpslocation/upload_location?status=1&lat=0.422005&lng=-122.084095&alt=0&mph=0.0&dir=0.0&dis=1.359023E7&lm=GPS&sid=4500352380545078953&acc=0.0&tm=1311847202000&tm2=28%20Jul%202011%2010:00:02%20GMT&did=10169

Answer (score 2):

Spaces to %20 are good idea.

**If there is more problematic characters:**

- Copy link to web browser and enter to it.
- Compare link before and after website download.
- Some malformed characters should be fixed to right form.

If it will fail also, please read this thread: [How to deal with the URISyntaxException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception).