# getting an error while making a request

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following in my URI

```
        uri.query = [id: "urn://salina/search/xplorer/XplorerApp",criteria:"{'includeNonGeotagged':'true','freetext':\{'text':" + "'" + "${searchString}" +"'}}",contentType:"rss20"]
```

I get an error saying java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 94: https://pix.us.baesystems.com/search/query?id=urn://salina/search/xplorer/XplorerApp&criteria={'includeNonGeotagged':'true','freetext':{'text':'test'}}&contentType=rss20

when I dump the value of uri.toString() and put it in a browser, it works fine, so I can't figure out what the issue here is...

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because there are unencoded chars in your URI. Try encoding them or first make a URL out of the string:

```
def url = "https://pix.us.baesystems.com/search/query?id=urn://salina/search/xplorer/XplorerApp&criteria={'includeNonGeotagged':'true','freetext':  {'text':'test'}}&contentType=rss20"
URL url = new URL(url);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null);
println uri
```

This will print the correct URI:

```
https://pix.us.baesystems.com/search/query?id=urn://salina/search/xplorer/XplorerApp&criteria=%7B'includeNonGeotagged':'true','freetext':%7B'text':'test'%7D%7D&contentType=rss20
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception) for the basic idea.