# java.net.URISyntaxException when downloading with DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, syntax, uri

I have programmed a class that get file with creating some parallel downloads. I use the simple code as below for any download :

```
DefaultHttpClient conn = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(new URI(M_url));
HttpResponse = conn.execute(httpPost);
```

In some file links (**M_url**) the program is okay, but when i want to download the link that contains the characters like **[ ]** URISyntaxException has occurred. For example, for the link `http://dl.androidiha.com/games/Dead-Rider-v2.5.2[Androidiha.com].zip` error is as below :

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 48:
>   http://dl.androidiha.com/games/Dead-Rider-v2.5.2[Androidiha.com].zipException
>   in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

What is the programmatically solution for solve this problem? I use the following code, but this can't solve my problem :

`M_url = URLEncoder.encode(M_url, "UTF-8")`

Thanks in advance and sorry if this topic duplicates with similar one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception .. perhaps this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe encoding maybe the answer. There is a similar topic existing on how to handle URISyntaxexception. 
[How to deal with the URISyntaxException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception)

I am sure you can solve the problem in a similar way