# JSON data not send using get method android

Tags: android, json, get

I am trying to send a JSON data using `DefaultHttpClient` using get method but it gives `404 error` when i encode JSON string using `URLEncode.encode()` method and if i directly pass JSON to url it gives `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index.` I have attached both url (encoded and non encoded) and stacktrace for both. my JSON is :

```
[{"Table":[{"PId":1376,"Box_Number":1,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1377,"Box_Number":2,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1378,"Box_Number":3,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1379,"Box_Number":4,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1380,"Box_Number":5,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1381,"Box_Number":6,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1382,"Box_Number":7,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1383,"Box_Number":8,"StartBalance":"15","Endbalance":"17","New":"15","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1384,"Box_Number":9,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1385,"Box_Number":10,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20}],"Table1":[{"OnlineSale":"7","PaidOut_Instant":"7","Paidout_Online":"7","Commission_instant":"7","COmmission_Online":"7","BooksSold":"0","Return":"7"}],"Table2":[{"EntryDate":"10/06/2017","EntryShift":"1"}]}]
```

Now encoded url is :

```
http://storeproductwebapi-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/LotteryEntry?StoreID=240&UserID=73&Shift=1&EntryDate=10%2F06%2F2017&JsonData=%5B%7B%22Table%22%3A%5B%7B%22PId%22%3A1376%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A1%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1377%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A2%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1378%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A3%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1379%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A4%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1380%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A5%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1381%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A6%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1382%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A7%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1383%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A8%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%2215%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%2217%22%2C%22New%22%3A%2215%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1384%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A9%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22PId%22%3A1385%2C%22Box_Number%22%3A10%2C%22StartBalance%22%3A%225%22%2C%22Endbalance%22%3A%227%22%2C%22New%22%3A%225%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A0%2C%22TicketsSold%22%3A2%2C%22TAmount%22%3A20%7D%5D%2C%22Table1%22%3A%5B%7B%22OnlineSale%22%3A%227%22%2C%22PaidOut_Instant%22%3A%227%22%2C%22Paidout_Online%22%3A%227%22%2C%22Commission_instant%22%3A%227%22%2C%22COmmission_Online%22%3A%227%22%2C%22BooksSold%22%3A%220%22%2C%22Return%22%3A%227%22%7D%5D%2C%22Table2%22%3A%5B%7B%22EntryDate%22%3A%2210%2F06%2F2017%22%2C%22EntryShift%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D%7D%5D
```

Here is it's Stacktrace :

```
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <head>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <style type="text/css">
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <!--
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): background-color:#555555;}
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): -->
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): </style>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): </head>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <body>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): <div id="content">
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321):  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321):   <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321):   <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321):  </fieldset></div>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): </div>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): </body>
10-06 11:12:05.749: E/jsonget(26321): </html>
```

Now second url without encoding :

```
http://storeproductwebapi-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/LotteryEntry?StoreID=240&UserID=73&Shift=1&EntryDate=10/06/2017&JsonData=[{"Table":[{"PId":1376,"Box_Number":1,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1377,"Box_Number":2,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1378,"Box_Number":3,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1379,"Box_Number":4,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1380,"Box_Number":5,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1381,"Box_Number":6,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1382,"Box_Number":7,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1383,"Box_Number":8,"StartBalance":"15","Endbalance":"17","New":"15","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1384,"Box_Number":9,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1385,"Box_Number":10,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20}],"Table1":[{"OnlineSale":"7","PaidOut_Instant":"7","Paidout_Online":"7","Commission_instant":"7","COmmission_Online":"7","BooksSold":"0","Return":"7"}],"Table2":[{"EntryDate":"10/06/2017","EntryShift":"1"}]}]
```

It's stacktrace :

```
 10-06 13:22:25.179: W/System.err(2913): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 139: http://storeproductwebapi-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/LotteryEntry?StoreID=240&UserID=73&Shift=1&EntryDate=10/06/2017&JsonData=[{"Table":[{"PId":1376,"Box_Number":1,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1377,"Box_Number":2,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1378,"Box_Number":3,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1379,"Box_Number":4,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1380,"Box_Number":5,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1381,"Box_Number":6,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1382,"Box_Number":7,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1383,"Box_Number":8,"StartBalance":"15","Endbalance":"17","New":"15","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1384,"Box_Number":9,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20},{"PId":1385,"Box_Number":10,"StartBalance":"5","Endbalance":"7","New":"5","BooksSold":0,"TicketsSold":2,"TAmount":20}],"Table1":[{"OnlineSale":"7","PaidOut_Instant":"7","Paidout_Online":"7","Commission_instant":"7","COmmission_Online":"7","BooksSold":"0","Return":"7"}],"Table2":[{"EntryDate":"10/06/2017","EntryShift":"1"}]}]
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at libcore.net.UriCodec.validate(UriCodec.java:63)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:406)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at hum.sub.ek.resources.JsonParser.putJson(JsonParser.java:200)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at hum.sub.ek.resources.LotterySetDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(LotterySetDataAsyncTask.java:66)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at hum.sub.ek.resources.LotterySetDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(LotterySetDataAsyncTask.java:1)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-06 13:22:25.189: W/System.err(2913):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The encoded url returns same `404 error` in browser but non encoded url runs perfectly in browser. Please help me to identify error.

Comment: I hope this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception

Comment: Maybe you are not encoding well the URI