# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name

Tags: curl, intellij-idea

I have this curl:

```
curl -i --user 'nuni:Iconi1080!' --noproxy '*' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "https://intratest.com/services/tomcat/v2/server/deploy" -d '{"user": "nuni" ,"name": "pol", "isName": "nuni8", "envName": "Dv", "tomcatEnvironment": "task", "applicationVersion": "0.0.1"}'
```

but when i run it thought Intelil I have this error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 4:
```

Comment: Can you specify how you are running your curl command through IntelliJ? The exception given only indicates that some java code attempted to parse a string that did not begin with "https://" as expected. Could it be attempting to parse "curl -i..." by mistake?

In IntelliJ the best way to execute a http command is with a .http requst file, which offers a handy curl conversion tool (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#converting-curl-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some empty spaces before or after *https:*, you should remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the java code but from examining the cURL you shared, I can see that you have a missing " after the word 'pol' in the JSON data part. so basically, the JSON seems broken, which could raise a problem later on in your java app.

Comment: there is no java code, I run it from the command line or Intellij window

Comment: Did adding the quote mark after pol worked for you? The cURL command sends the payload to https://test.com/services/tomcat/v2/server/deploy with the credentials. What is the code behind this endpoint. I believe the exception is raised from there

Comment: I added it with the same result

Comment: test.com/services/tomcat/v2/server/deploy doesn't seem like the actual endpoint you are using. Is there a different endpoint you are pointing to in your development environment?  I saw that you edited the JSON data payload in your question, which is good, but if the issue persists, I still think we need to understand what's going on at the endpoint part as the exception seems to be bubbling from there. Please try to provide additional information.

Comment: test.com is in fact an Intranet endPoint

Comment: OK, did you write the code for this endpoint? can you share it? I want to see if there is any part of your code that uses new URL(...) or new URI(...) - and check the actual URI/URL which is provided to it. This is probably an issue that indicates that the url/uri string is not encoded properly. See here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749709/how-to-deal-with-the-urisyntaxexception